# C: How do I setup Openssl to be used on mingw for windows?

Tags: c, openssl, mingw

I tried downloading the binaries and even putting the openssl under includes folder in the src path, none of those worked. Any ideas on how I could install openssl on windows for mingw ex: `#include <openssl/ssl.h>`

Comment: If you are using msys, then install with pacman.

Comment: I tried doing pacman -S openssl and pacman -S openssl-devel but even after installing them I still get `fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: That probably means you are missing `-I /mingw64/include` when compiling.  You also need `-L /mingw64/lib` when linking.  Do not move files around.

Comment: I am using Clion to edit/compile the code and i setup the toolchain with mingw but it says that it cannot find mingw32/include when compiling: `mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** No rule to make target '/mingw32/lib', needed by 'Project.exe'.  Stop.`

Comment: Are you using the old mingw.org or the new mingw-w64.org?

Comment: I am using the new mingw-w64.